# text-align right in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox, and elements in it are "p" elements.

I'm trying to align it right, but it's still not working and everything is still aligned center.

```css
.box1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: right;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Is it possible to align it right?

Comment: we need to see your HTML too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align-items: flex-end;` will align the `<p>` elements to the right side of the container, but only if the container's width is greater than the children's width.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 3px;
}

p {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right; // you might also want to use this so that your text is aligned to the far right side.
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid lime 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Testing 1...</p>
  <p>Testing 2...</p>
  <p>Testing 3...</p>
  <p>Testing 4...</p>
</div>
```

Flex boxes can be a bit tricky since the `justify-content` property always aligns content in the same direction of the flex box (i.e. vertically for columns and horizontally for rows), whereas `align-items` always aligns content in the cross direction (i.e. horizontally for columns and vertically for rows). For example...

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content:; /* aligns content vertically */
align-items:; /* aligns content horizontally */

display: flex;
/* flex-direction: row; is the default value */
justify-content:; /* aligns content horizontally */
align-items:; /* aligns content vertically */
```

Comment: I also tried align items. But end in column orientation is actually a bottom of a column...

Comment: @Tatjana does this explain and fix your problem?

Comment: Your solution worked only when i added text align to paragraph) But thank you anyway

Comment: @Tatjana the demo in my answer shows you exactly whats happening. `align-items: flex-end` aligns the **elements** to the right side, but text stuff by default is aligned to the left, so it will appear as if it isnt aligned to the right if the width of the text stuff is less than the width of their container.

Answer (score -2):

Apply the text-align to the paragraphs:

```
.box1 p {
  text-align: right;
}
```